# How to set pitch value of a video?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I created a demo app like tom cat with the help of [this](http://purplelilgirl.tumblr.com/post/9377269385/making-that-talking-app). In this link, we can set pitch value of an audio using `CDSoundEngine`. However, I want to set pitch value of a video. How can I do that?

Comment: how do you play the video?

Comment: I play video from iphone photo library.

Comment: No, I mean with which video player? MPMoviePlayerController? If yes, check the docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html I don't see any way to pitch audio, and it's very uncommon to have such a feature for videos as you would normally have to re-encode the entire video. Unless you can hook between the player and audio output, like plugins of desktop video players can do. I doubt something like that is possible on iOS though. Not with MPMoviePlayer anyway.

Comment: I merged images array and audio and create new video and I want to set pitch value of newly created video. when we play new video ,audio should be in funny voice like tomcat. I saved this video in photo library.

Comment: Well then I would look into modifying the audio before you merge it with the video.

Answer (score 0):

There is a scaleTimeRange method in the AVMutableCompositionTrack that can be used for setting the speed of video playback.